# Notation for set excluding element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Consider the set $\mathbb{A}=\{a,b,c\}$.

I want to refer to "the set $\mathbb{A}$ excluding the element $a$"

Is the notation $\mathbb{A} \sim  \{a\}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{A} \setminus \{a\}$?

Is the former an abuse of logic notation?

The latter is what I am used to.

Comment: Was it possibly hand-written? Because then it could have been a sloppily written $A-\{a\}$.

Comment: @celtschk, good point. Yes it was an informal remark (but typed, not handwritten). But from someone who is usually very careful! I've edited the question since I am still interested in knowing if this is generally seen as 'sloppy'

Comment: Usually not; see [Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)). In set theory, the symbol $\sim$ is already used for [Equinumerosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity).

Comment: Also note that "the set $\mathbb{A}$ excluding the element $\{a\}$" would mean $\mathbb{A}\backslash\{\{a\}\}$.
What you probably mean is "the set $\mathbb{A}$ excluding the element $a$"

Comment: @ cdwe yes. I mean element. fixed the question

Comment: I'm sure I've seen $A\mathbin{\sim}B$ to denote $A\setminus B$; there's no real consensus on such notation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The notation $\Bbb A - \{a\}$ is often used to mean the same thing as $\Bbb A \setminus \{a\}$ (the [set difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html)), but I've never seen it with a tilde and can't find any references to it being used this way with Google.

The tilde $\sim$ is sometimes used as a negation or "not" symbol in set theory, in which case

$$\Bbb A \setminus \{a\} = \bigl\{x : x \in \Bbb A, \sim\!(x\in\{a\})\bigr\}.$$

The tilde is also used sometimes for [equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), where $x \sim y$ means $x$ and $y$ are equivalent (in the same equivalence class) under some equivalence relation $\sim$.

A particularly common example of this is with the cardinality of sets. We say $A \sim B$ if $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, that is $|A| = |B|$, and we call them [equinumerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity).

Comment: Thanks – makes all sense. @egreg, do you have any reference where $A\sim B$ is used to denote $A \setminus B$?

Comment: Kelley uses the tilde with this meaning in “[Decomposition and representation theorems in measure theory](https://eudml.org/doc/161354)”, Math. Ann. 163 (1966).